# Balanced Multiline TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-wrap-content

I am starting with this:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Here is what it looks like"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Which renders like this:

```
| Here is what it looks |
|         like          |
```

But I want it to render like this:

```
|      Here is what     |
|     it looks like     |
```

Is there a way to do this without customizing the built in `TextView`? If not, how can `TextView` be customized to do this?

Note that the `android:text` value is actually filled in programmatically and can vary in content/length. I am looking for a general solution that works for any text value on any screen width.

Comment: Maybe adding padding to your TextView will help you achieve something close to this

Answer (score 15):

Starting in API 23, `TextView` has [break strategy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy) and [hyphenation frequency](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hyphenationFrequency) settings that can be used to achieve this.

```
<TextView
    android:text="Here is what it looks like"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
    android:breakStrategy="balanced"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

However, I don't see any way to do this for API <23. [AppCompatTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html) in version 23.1.0 of the support library doesn't seem to support these.

NOTE: Android Studio 1.4.1 does not show the desired wrapping behavior in the preview window (even when API 23 is selected for the preview), but it can be seen in an emulated API 23 device.

Comment: I have filed two bugs on this: [request to backport on the support library](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203863) and [hyphenation only works in English](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203895).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just layout_alignparent_left with gravity center.